# Neo4j - null collect causing "odd number of arguments for Hash" in converting results to array of hashes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, neo4j, cypher

I'm returning a collection of comments in [cypher](/questions/tagged/cypher) (neo4j 1.9) and all is well.

When there are no comments the collect is `[ ]`..

Ok, so this works well in the console - see the results?

```
==> | 5548       | [ ]  |
==> | 5552       | [Node[5554]{views:0, comment:"test"},Node[5552]{views:0,comment:"terrible"},Node[5550]{views:0,comment:"RIP"}] |
```

The problem is node *5548*, with an *empty* collection of `[]`, causes this piece of Ruby on Rails (V1.9.3) code to bomb:

```
array_of_hashes = results["data"].map {|row| Hash[*results["columns"].zip(row).flatten] }
```

The error I receive is:

```
odd number of arguments for Hash
```

If I filter out *5548* with a where statement in [cypher](/questions/tagged/cypher), no problem.. If I don't filter or filter for to get node *5548*, it bombs.

`results["data"].map {|row| Hash[*results["columns"].zip(row)] }` returns: `[{}]` for this record. So basically the lack of arguments (or an odd number of them) is causing problems..

So, the question is, what is the best way to avoid this in either Cypher or ROR?  Could I replace occurrences of `[ ]` in the collect column with something else before doing the conversion to an array of hashes? Maybe replace the `[ ]` the structure of the nodes that have data with empty values like such:

replace `[ ]` in record *5548* with `[Node[0]{views:0, comment:""}]`, which would then make node *5548* look like this in the resulting data:

```
5548         | [Node[0]{views:0, comment:""}] |
```

after which the conversion to an array_of_hashes would/should work well..

Any answers or suggestions?

1. The bad `result` is:

   ```
   {"columns"=>["collect(comment_list)"], "data"=>[[[]]]}
   ```
2. The good `result` is:

   ```
   {"columns"=>["cl"], "data"=>[[[{"extensions"=>{}, "paged_traverse"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5554/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}", "outgoing_relationships"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5554/relationships/out", "traverse"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5554/traverse/{returnType}", "all_typed_relationships"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5554/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}", "property"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5554/properties/{key}", "all_relationships"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5554/relationships/all", "self"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5554", "properties"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5554/properties", "outgoing_typed_relationships"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5554/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}", "incoming_relationships"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5554/relationships/in", "incoming_typed_relationships"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5554/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}", "create_relationship"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5554/relationships", "data"=>{"comment"=>"test", "author_id"=>"5338", "out"=>"out of ourder", "votes"=>0, "type"=>"comment", "spam"=>false, "shares"=>0, "dislikes"=>0, "abuse"=>false, "copywriteviolation"=>false, "comments"=>0, "likes"=>0, "views"=>0}}, {"extensions"=>{}, "paged_traverse"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5552/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}", "outgoing_relationships"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5552/relationships/out", "traverse"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5552/traverse/{returnType}", "all_typed_relationships"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5552/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}", "property"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5552/properties/{key}", "all_relationships"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5552/relationships/all", "self"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5552", "properties"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5552/properties", "outgoing_typed_relationships"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5552/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}", "incoming_relationships"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5552/relationships/in", "incoming_typed_relationships"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5552/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}", "create_relationship"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5552/relationships", "data"=>{"comment"=>"terrible", "author_id"=>"5338", "out"=>"out of ourder", "votes"=>0, "type"=>"comment", "spam"=>false, "shares"=>0, "dislikes"=>0, "abuse"=>false, "copywriteviolation"=>false, "comments"=>0, "likes"=>0, "views"=>0}}, {"extensions"=>{}, "paged_traverse"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5550/paged/traverse/{returnType}{?pageSize,leaseTime}", "outgoing_relationships"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5550/relationships/out", "traverse"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5550/traverse/{returnType}", "all_typed_relationships"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5550/relationships/all/{-list|&|types}", "property"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5550/properties/{key}", "all_relationships"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5550/relationships/all", "self"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5550", "properties"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5550/properties", "outgoing_typed_relationships"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5550/relationships/out/{-list|&|types}", "incoming_relationships"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5550/relationships/in", "incoming_typed_relationships"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5550/relationships/in/{-list|&|types}", "create_relationship"=>"http://localhost:7474/db/data/node/5550/relationships", "data"=>{"comment"=>"RIP", "author_id"=>"5338", "out"=>"out of ourder", "votes"=>0, "type"=>"comment", "spam"=>false, "shares"=>0, "dislikes"=>0, "abuse"=>false, "copywriteviolation"=>false, "comments"=>0, "likes"=>0, "views"=>0}}]]]}
   ```

Comment: which is value of `results["columns"].zip(row)` for 5548?

Comment: results["data"].map {|row| Hash[*results["columns"].zip(row)] } returns: [{}]

Comment: but where is the error `The error I receive is: odd number of arguments for Hash`?

Comment: This gives me that error:  array_of_hashes = results["data"].map {|row| Hash[*results["columns"].zip(row).flatten] }

Comment: I think it's because Ruby 1.93 can't deal with a null hash when attempting this.. I think 2.0 works with it.. but I can't switch so am stuck with this..

Comment: specifically, 1.9.3-p429

Comment: `Hash[{}] => {} ` ruby 1.9.3-p484

Comment: why you don't wish to updete build version?

Comment: So should I use 1.9.3-p484 instead?

Comment: I can do that.. just don't want to go to version 2..

Comment: So if I upgrade to 1.9.3-p484 it will get rid of this issue?

Comment: I can't fully reproduce, please give me the exact data value: `results` hash for 5548.

Comment: HERE IS THE VALUE FOR RESULTS:  {"columns"=>["collect(comment_list)"], "data"=>[[[]]]}

Comment: and provide the same for well data.

Comment: For a good row: array_of_hashes = results["data"].map {|row| Hash[*results["columns"].zip(row)] }   I get back [{}]

Comment: Added the "flatten" version to the end of the question  - too long for a comment.. Look for your name at the bottom of the question and you'll see what a good row looks like that does not cause the odd number error message.

Comment: I mean the same as `{"columns"=>["collect(comment_list)"], "data"=>[[[]]]} `, but for good result

Comment: Ok added to the top.. too long for a comment

Comment: i have the same result: `ArgumentError: odd number of arguments for Hash`

Comment: I meant not result of execution if the line: `results["data"].map {|row| Hash[*results["columns"].zip(row).flatten] } ` but input data to it: that is `result` variable for both cases. Have you get it?

Comment: ok.. i posted back up top at the bottom of the question.. quite a bit of data in there.. still won't fit, but I think it's what you are looking for.. And the bad rows return  {"columns"=>["collect(comment_list)"], "data"=>[[[]]]}

Comment: and `result` for bad too

Comment: {"columns"=>["collect(comment_list)"], "data"=>[[[]]]}  is the bad result

Comment: see here: `results["data"].map {|row| p Hash[*results["columns"].zip(row).flatten].keys }` this come outputs strange result for good case (it has strange second key)

Comment: Ok.. now when I try to to access ["data"] of the results, I get "can't convert String into Integer" error.. Example:   array_of_hashes =results["data"].map {|row| p Hash[*results["columns"].zip(row).flatten] }
   raise array_of_hashes["data"].to_s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code:

```
results["data"].map do|row|
   a = results["columns"].zip(row).flatten
   a << nil if a.size % 2 > 0
   Hash[*a]
end
```

but as I denoted the array `results["columns"].zip(row).flatten].keys` has mixed up the keys, and values in the good case. I believe, you have to revise the transform procedure.

Comment: ary=results["data"].map do|row|
      a = results["columns"].zip(row).flatten
      a << nil if a.size % 2 > 0
      Hash[*a]
   end
   
   raise ary[0]["cl"]["data"].to_s

Comment: results in {"comment"=>"test", "author_id"=>"5338", "out"=>"out of ourder", "votes"=>0, "type"=>"comment", "spam"=>false, "shares"=>0, "dislikes"=>0, "abuse"=>false, "copywriteviolation"=>false, "comments"=>0, "likes"=>0, "views"=>0}

Comment: How do I access the second and third records?  using ary[0]["cl"]["data"].to_s I can get the first record but how do I get send and third?

Comment: OK.. this is great!  In my controller I can access each key etc.  But in my view I cannot!

Comment: Only one row of comment data is displayed in the view.. If I display the entire object I see all the comments.. but when I call <%=activity["cl"]%> I only see the first comment.

Comment: @RubenCatchmeObregon pass the value to view as a local variable, ad you will get access it in view

Comment: I do this and use a .each to pass to a partial..  but it only grabs the first comment - I think the structure of the data is not correct. I'm going to try another approach.. thanks for your help